# Performance question: Inverting an array of pointers in-place vs array of values

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, matrix, inversion

The background for asking this question is that I am solving a linearized equation system (Ax=b), where A is a matrix (typically of dimension less than 100x100) and x and b are vectors. I am using a direct method, meaning that I first invert A, then find the solution by x=A^(-1)b. This step is repated in an iterative process until convergence.

*The way I'm doing it now, using a matrix library (MTL4):*
For every iteration I copy all coeffiecients of A (values) in to the matrix object, then invert. This the easiest and safest option.

*Using an array of pointers instead:*
For my particular case, the coefficients of A happen to be updated between each iteration. These coefficients are stored in different variables (some are arrays, some are not). Would there be a potential for performance gain if I set up A as an array containing pointers to these coefficient variables, then inverting A in-place?

The nice thing about the last option is that once I have set up the pointers in A before the first iteration, I would not need to copy any values between successive iterations. The values which are pointed to in A would automatically be updated between iterations.

So the performance question boils down to this, as I see it:
 - The matrix inversion process takes roughly the same amount of time, assuming de-referencing of pointers is non-expensive.
 - The array of pointers does not need the extra memory for matrix A containing values.
 - The array of pointers option does not have to copy all NxN values of A between each iteration.
 - The values that are pointed to the array of pointers option are generally NOT ordered in memory. Hopefully, all values lie relatively close in memory, but *A[0][1] is generally not next to *A[0][0] etc.

Any comments to this? Will the last remark affect performance negatively, thus weighing up for the positive performance effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test, test, test.

Especially in the field of Numerical Linear Algebra. There are many effects in play, which is why there is a number of optimized libraries that have solved that burden for you.

Some effects to consider:

- Memory locality and cache effects
- Multithreading effects (some algorithms that are optimal while running single-core, cause memory collision/cache eviction when more than one core is utilized).

There is no substitute for testing.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I agree. I have prepared everything for testing actually, it's just that I need to do some changes to get it working.. It isn't as straightforward as indicated in the first post.. That's why I wanted to ask; if it has a big potential and if it is worth investing the effort of extensive testing.

Comment: +1 for Test and also cache effects. By definition, the pointers will about double the memory used which will hurt cache performance.

Comment: I've seen performance difference of around 80x between a naive cache-unaware implementation and one that pays some attention to the sequence of memory accesses. There are two good tools on Linux to use it, one is called kcachegrind (which is a frontend to valgrind, a great all-round memory profiler and debugger engine), and the other one is OProfile - lots of CPU performance counters to watch and learn how cache misses and digital electronics affect your performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some comments:

- Is the function you use for the inversion capable of handling a matrix of pointers instead of values? If it does not realise it has to do an indirection, all kinds of strange effects could happen.
- When doing an in-place matrix inversion (meaning the inverted matrix overwrites the input matrix), **all** input coefficients will get overwritten with new values, because matrix inversion can not be done by re-ordering the elements of the matrix.
- During the inversion process, none of the input coefficients may be changed by an outside process. All such updates have to be performed between iterations.

So, you get the following set of trade-offs when you chose the pointer solution:

- The coefficients making up matrix A can no longer be calculated asynchronously with the matrix inversion.
- Either **all** coefficients must be recalculated for each iteration (when you use in-place inversion, meaning the inverted matrix uses the same memory as the input matrix), or you still have to use a matrix of N x N values to hold the result of the inversion.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, I have changed an LU inversion function to handle a pointer matrix. And, since the linearized equation system is representing a non-linear system with Newtons method, the update of coefficients MUST happen between iterations. I.e. the matrix coefficients cannot be updated asynchronously, even if we wanted. Also, all coefficients are recalculated for each iteration (by a third party software). So your comments are accounted for, but I see some challenges when the SAME coefficient is supposed to be several places in the matrix.. Then I need extra memory for those..

Answer (score 0):

You're getting good answers here. The only thing I would add is some general experience with performance.

You are thinking about performance a-priori. That's reasonable, but the real payoff is a-posteriori. In other words, you don't know for certain where the real optimization opportunities are, until the running code tells you.

You don't know if the bulk of the time will be spent in matrix inversion, multiplication, copying the matrix, dereferencing, or what. People can guess. If I had to guess, it would be matrix inversion, because it's 100x100.
However, something else I can't guess might be even bigger.
Guessing has a very poor track record, especially when you can just *find out*.

[Here's an example of what I mean.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773)